# Windows Phone 7 - Online Database

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

i need your help. I was wondering if there are any tutorials or books that would explain to me how to connect to a database through the internet... i want to create a news application that would read directly from the news database... and then if i want to allow users to post comments.

I searched online alot for this and couldnt find any hints or guides. If anyone could help me out in pointing me into the right direction i'd really appreciate it.

Thank you

EDIT:  Any way to read arabic rss feeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using WCF to connect to Database. I have done it before and is pretty straight forward.

[Querying a database on Windows Phone 7 using WCF](http://www.studentguru.gr/blogs/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx)

Comment: thank you alot for your reply.... i was also wondering if you have any idea of any news server online that i could use to test it out?

Comment: well.. the above solution is more valid when you have your own database. News websites like CNN etc won't allow you to access their database / servers like that.. Maybe you want to look into reading/ displaying feeds from news websites.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is a RSS Reader, your feed could be formatted in all sorts, JSON or XML which would probably be easier and quicker, also News feeds often come in XML format for RSS Readers I myself have done just that

Tutorial #1
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows

Tutorial #2
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/02/03/reading-rss-items-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

News Feed
http://www.guardian.co.uk/football/premierleague+tone/matchreports/rss

The great thing is, you dont have to do any work after this, if the News Feed belongs to a popular Organisation and is of course open to the public, it will be up to date and always available

Comment: this is great, however its not working on the site i want to get the feeds from... keeps giving me internet connection error although all other feeds of mashable update normally. ... is there any book that would teach me everything regarding databases , rss on windows phone 7?

Comment: are you sure the website is providing such a feed? and if I was you I would perhaps look around the internet on teaching how to make a RSS Reader, there is two tutorials above I dont understand how you need a book to learn this. You DONT want to use a database for this unless your creating your own information.